# How to make a bootstrap modal window close when click outside again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm working in a project using bootstrap framework and I read there are different ways to open a modal window, in my case I open it with javascript with this code:

```
$('#formVenta').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
```

I did this because the client asked me to avoid close the modal when click outside but now he wants to press click outside and close the modal again but when there is no content inside a specific div inside my window

`<div id="content_goes_here"></div>`

I think to solve this in this way

```
$(document).click(function(e) {

        //check if modal is open
        if ($('#formVenta').is(':visible')) {

            //check if div has content
            if ($('#content_goes_here').html().length > 0) {

                //do something
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem I see is that there are text input outside that `div` and If I want to search something it will close when I make click in the input because there will be not content yet inside the `div` and I want to avoid this issue.

Is there a way where only when I make click outside the modal window check if the `div` is empty and make the opposite of the way I opened the window in this case the opposite of this?

```
$('#formVenta').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
```

for example change the value of the property `backgrop`.

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: so only close the modal if there is **no** text inside a specific div element, otherwise it must stay open if there **is** content inside a specific div element?

Comment: @Andrei as I said in the question when I open the modal window in that way I cant close it making click outside because of `backdrop` property, now I want a way to change its value to make possible close the window again making click outside, I hope I explained well

Comment: is it possible to check if the div has any content before you run `$('#formVenta').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});` if you can check if the div has content first then you don't add the `backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false' to the modal`. I can't really see the full workflow here hopefully this can be done

Comment: Yes but now If I add content to that div I want to make the modal to no close when make click outside, see my point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry it took a while to find the right properties but here is the best example

`$('#formVenta').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = false;` or
`$('#formVenta').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = static;`

you can take a look at the current properties you have set by doing
`alert(JSON.stringify($('#myModal3').data('bs.modal').options));` or change the alert to `console.log()`

so you can put an event on the div for when it changes to run the validation function and inside of the validation function you can change the options of the modal with the above code

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and I will let you know what happen but I think will solve my problem, thank you.

Comment: As I said, I tried this and it worked really well, thank you for you help, can you tell me where did you find this info? by the way I just changed `$('#formVenta').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = static;` for `$('#formVenta').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';` static needs quotes.

Comment: I don't remember exactly where it's been a while since I've seen the docs but I did remember seeing it within the bootstrap docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/) use CTRL+F for **bs.modal** I can't seem to find the example anymore

Comment: It's ok, thank you again, you were the only one who understood what I was looking for.